# Java audio plays fine when run alone, not when run through separate class

Tags: java, audio, java-io

So this class plays the sound file 'Theme A.wav' just fine when ran by itself.

This is 'PlayAudio.class'

```
import java.io.*;
import sun.audio.*;

public class PlayAudio {

public static playsound() {

  String sound = "Theme A.wav";

  InputStream audio = new FileInputStream(new File(sound));
  AudioStream aStream = new AudioStream(audio);
  AudioPlayer.player.start(aStream);

    System.out.println("Loaded playaudio.class; playing audio");


}
public static void main(String args[]) {

new playsound();

}
}
```

However, the play button found in the main class, fails to call 'playaudio.class when clicked. It worked fine before I added the audio code (everything but the 'System.out.println("Loaded playaudio.class; playing audio");' line). The error didn't show up until the "throws Exception" snippet was added to the first class.

```
//play button
play = new JButton(new ImageIcon ("UIImages/play.png"));
play.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
play.setFocusPainted(false);

//sets up the action play
play.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

       PlayAudio.playsound();

    }
  });
```

Any help?
This is the exception the compiler throws.

```
1 error found:
File: C:\Users\Hunter\workspace\src\rejomedia.java  [line: 74]
Error: Unhandled exception type java.lang.Exception
```

Comment: And what does the exception say?

Comment: Added to the qestion.

Comment: If you don't mind a couple suggestions: you should call your playaudio class PlayAudio--Classes start with capitals like that, methods start with lower case (so "main" is correct).  #2 what you have is a build error, not an exception.  Exceptions are only when you are running the program (java) not compiling it (javac).  #3, take that code out of main and put it into another method like "playSound", then have both your main and the event handler call "playSound" which seems much better than calling "main" directly.

Comment: Edited, did you mean something like that? The compiler then throws a 'Return type for method is missing.' error. I'm assuming this is because 'playsound' is not the class file's name?

Comment: Okay, close.  playsound needs to return something, make it's type "void".  inside your main and inside your actionPerformed should look like this:  "new PlayAudio().playsound()".  Either that or make playsound static and it can be "PlayAudio.playsound()".  I'm sorry this stuff is really confusing and pointless at first but I promise that when you use it a lot all these strange gotchas are really useful.

Comment: By the way, if you can I highly recommend that you download an editor: Eclipse or Netbeans (They are both free).  If you go through the time to set one up it will point out code problems like this very quickly--it's one of the biggest advantages of Java--that it's so easy to find code problems--but without an editor java can be Very Frustrating, especially if you are new to Java.

Comment: I use DrJava, does that count? And I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a Try/Catch around playaudio.main(null) or inside your main (instead of throwing).

The playaudio.main() call will throw into the action event listener and will probably be eaten silently.  Silent exceptions are absolutely the worst thing you can have in Java code.

My guess is it's throwing out because it can't find the file any more (Possibly the "." directory moved because you are starting it differently or using a different main)

If that's the case, one way to "Fix" it is to supply the full path.

If you are seeing an exception, then please add it to  your post and we can assist further.

Got it.  It's a build error.  When you "Throw" your exception from your main you aren't handling it in the method that calls your main.

Same solution as I gave above.  Wrap the call to main in a try/catch:

```
try {
    playaudio.main(null);
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Caught an exception:"+ e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: instead of '    System.out.println("Caught an exception:", e.getMessage());' it's '    System.out.println("Caught an exception:" + e.getMessage());' that seems to have done the trick! :D